# React - Loop through an array of objects, and highlight the selected item onClick

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

I have an array of objects which holds data, which I output to the DOM using map. Each item in the list, has a onClick event listener. When you click on one of the items, I want it to be highlighted by way of adding a css class, for example ‘hover’. So basically it should work like a menu system. When you click on an item, that item is highlighted and the others should not be highlighted and vice versa.

The way i have it set up right now, all of the items in the list get highlighted, which is not the logic i’m trying to do. I have used console.log, to display which item has been clicked. However, I still have not figured out, how to make that selected item, the one thats highlighted instead of the whole list?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class MenuSelector extends Component {
    state = {
        active: false,
        menu: [
            {
                id: 1,
                fighterName: 'Goku',
                race: 'Sayian',
                specialAttack: 'Kamehameha Wave',
                img: 'https://nerdist.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/Dragon-Ball-Super-Goku.jpg'
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                fighterName: 'Vegeta',
                race: 'Sayian',
                specialAttack: 'Final Flash',
                img: 'https://imgmr.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/Vegeta-SSGSS-2.png'
            },
            {
                id: 3,
                fighterName: 'Gohun',
                race: 'Human',
                specialAttack: 'Masenko',
                img: 'https://techanimate.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/Why-does-Gohan-Have-so-much-Hidden-Power-1024x576.jpg'
            },
            {
                id: 4,
                fighterName: 'Krillin',
                race: 'Human',
                specialAttack: 'Destructo Disc',
                img: 'https://static3.srcdn.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/Krillin-Destructo-Disk.jpg'
            },
            {
                id: 5,
                fighterName: 'Android 17',
                race: 'Android',
                specialAttack: 'Barrier',
                img: 'https://i.ytimg.com/vi/SzAiIy_Dnb4/maxresdefault.jpg'
            },
            {
                id: 6,
                fighterName: 'Jiren',
                race: 'Unknown',
                specialAttack: 'Eye Paralysis',
                img: 'https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/dragonuniverse/images/9/9c/Jiren.png/revision/latest/scale-to-width-down/2000?cb=20180211002429'
            },
            {
                id: 7,
                fighterName: 'Lord Beerus',
                race: 'God',
                specialAttack: 'Hakai',
                img: 'https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/dragonuniverse/images/3/30/Beerus2.png/revision/latest?cb=20170225064338'
            },
            {
                id: 8,
                fighterName: 'Cell',
                race: 'Android',
                specialAttack: 'Kamehameha Wave',
                img: 'https://static0.srcdn.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/Dragon-Ball-Z-Perfect-Cell.jpg'
            },
            {
                id: 9,
                fighterName: 'Frieza',
                race: 'Unknown',
                specialAttack: 'Finger Blasters',
                img: 'https://i.ytimg.com/vi/BkoOw_7JqKg/maxresdefault.jpg'
            },
            {
                id: 10,
                fighterName: 'Black Goku',
                race: 'Sayian',
                specialAttack: 'Ki Blade',
                img: 'https://pm1.narvii.com/6287/eafbdf4dc0ae1b58d3869b89be04bcd0712f7623_hq.jpg'
            },
        ]
    }
    toggleClass = (id) => {
        console.log(`Clicked item ${id}`, this);

        const currentState = this.state.active;
        this.setState({ active: !currentState });
    };

    selectHandler = (id) => {
        console.log(`Clicked item ${id}`);
        console.log(this);

    }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <h1>Menu Selector</h1>
        <div>
        <ul>
            {this.state.menu.map((dragonball, index) => (
                <li key={index} onClick={() => this.toggleClass(dragonball.id)} className={this.state.active ? 'hover': null}>
                <div className="container-dragonball">
                <div className="dragonball-stats">
                <h1>{dragonball.fighterName}</h1>
                <p>Race: {dragonball.race}</p>
                <p>Special Attack: {dragonball.specialAttack}</p>
                </div>
                <div className="dragonball-img"><img src={dragonball.img} alt={dragonball.fighterName} /></div>
                </div>
                </li>
            ))}
            </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default MenuSelector;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated   `toggleClass` to add a `selected item id` to state.

```
toggleClass = (id) => {

        this.setState({ selectedItemIndex: id });
    };
```

Now,
modifed `li` with

`className={this.state.selectedItemIndex== dragonball.id? 'hover': null}`.

Loop `menu` and check for `selected item id`. Add a required class if there is match for `id`

```
    <li key={index} onClick={() => this.toggleClass(dragonball.id)} 
className={this.state.selectedItemIndex== dragonball.id? 'hover': null}>
```

Comment: Thanks the solution you provided worked. Just one thing. I think its supposed to be "===" instead of "==". It was flagged as an error when i complied it. So the below amended code is probably more ideal.

<li key={index} onClick={() => this.toggleClass(dragonball.id)} 
                 className={this.state.selectedItemIndex === dragonball.id ? 'hover': null}>

Comment: Sorry,my bad.=== better but make sure response consistent datatype for it

Comment: @AndrewBaisden if its working fine then please accept and upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

This way you can select multiple

```
 handleSelect = ( id) => {
    const selection = this.state.selected
    if (this.state.selected[id] == 1) {
      selection[id] = 0 //deselect the item
    } else selection[id] = 1 //select the item
    this.setState({ selected: selection }, () =>
      console.log(this.state.selected)
    )
  }
```

then add your className like this

```
<li className={ ` ${this.state.selected[dragonball.id] == 1 && "selected"}` }>
```